# Why is the infinite loop error happening?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I can't understand why does it say it will create an infinite loop.It doesn't seem like it will.What's the problem?

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {

    var max = arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return Math.max(a, b);
    });
    var min = arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return Math.min(a, b);
    });
    var allNums = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= (max ^ 3); i++) {
            allNums.push(i * j);
        }
    }

}


smallestCommons([1, 6]);
```

Comment: Note, `^` is the bitwise XOR operator, not "to the power of". You want [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) for that. `6^3` is `5`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `j` is never increasing so it always matches the condition in `j<=(max^3)` inside your `for` loop.

I think there is a typo:

```
for(var j=1;j<=(max^3);i++) {
```

should be

```
for (var j=1; j <= (max^3); j++) {
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for(var j=1;j<=(max^3);i++)
```

Should be

```
for(var j=1;j<=(max^3);j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change 
 `for(var j = 1 ; j <= (max^3) ; i++)` 
to 
`for(var j = 1 ; j <= (max^3) ; j++)`

Answer (score 0):

Your nested for loop never increments your var j.

```
for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= (max ^ 3); j++) {
            allNums.push(i * j);
        }
    }
```